# Cascaded LEFT JOIN v.s. sub-select

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I have 2 queries:

1)

```
    SELECT person.idx, person.name, groups.idx
      FROM people
 LEFT JOIN membership
        ON membership.person=person.idx
 LEFT JOIN groups
        ON groups.name='supervisors'
       AND membership.group=groups.idx
```

2)

```
   SELECT person.idx, person.name, a.idx
     FROM people
LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT group.idx, membership.person
             FROM groups, membership
            WHERE membership.group=group.idx
              AND group.name='supervisors') a
       ON a.person=person.idx
```

These queries have been simplified but the core logic is the same.  They *seem* to be equivalent.  The 1st seems "cleaner" syntactically.  I'm not an SQL expert, and am pretty new to LEFT JOIN in particular, but it seems to be the way to answer this kind of membership question, where one table contains a subset of information about another table. Is this the right approach?

Comment: You mentioned LEFT JOIN, but I cannot see any LEFT JOINs in your queries.

Comment: Sorry!  Of course, they're LEFT, or OUTER joins.

Comment: Number 1 would have better performance

Comment: There are three kinds of outer joins--left, right & full. PS Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: T t INNER JOIN U u ON c is (t.t1,...,u.u1,...) rows where (t.t1,...) IN T AND (u.u1,...) IN U AND c. T t LEFT JOIN U u ON c is (t.t1,...,u.u1,...) rows where (t.t1,...) IN T AND ((u.u1,...) IN U AND c OR NOT EXISTS u.u1,... [(u.u1,...) IN U AND c] AND u.u1 IS NULL AND ...). People build queries using these intuitively but don't know how to justify their choices. [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

The two queries are not the same.  The first returns rows for *all* groups a person is a member of, with the `idx` of the "supervisors" where appropriate.

The second returns one row for each member, with the idx of the "supervisors" group where appropriate.  You should choose the version that does what you want.

Once you have the logic that you want, then in MySQL, it is usually best to avoid subqueries in the `FROM` clause if possible.  MySQL has a tendency to materialize them, which makes optimizations more difficult (I think this has gotten better in more recent versions).

Also, you should eschew commas in the `FROM` clause and always use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: It's the 2nd behavior I want.  Can I do it without the sub-select?

Answer (score 0):

Poor form to answer my own question?

This seems to work:

```
     SELECT person.idx, person.name, groups.idx
      FROM people
LEFT JOIN (groups, membership)
       ON groups.name='supervisors'
      AND groups.person=person.idx
      AND membership.group=groups.idx
```

Maybe a MySQL only extension?

Comment: If you read the MySQL JOIN documentation, they have an extension where you can put comma lists of tables in parentheses rather than only not in parentheses. Comma means CROSS JOIN with lower precedence than keyword joins. INNER JOIN ON c returns CROSS JOIN WHERE c; CROSS JOIN means INNER JOIN ON true.

Comment: Using standard SQL this is p left join (g cross join m) on c, also (ignoring column order) g cross join m right join p on c. Read an introduction and/or the manual & find out what joins calculate.